# Php get webfolder address

Tags: php, document-root

I would like to know what PHP function/keyword I can use so that I can always get to the root of my webfolder. I'm using apache server with xampp.

I have a web folder by the name 'test1', so it's in the following path:
D:\xampp\htdocs\test1

Currently I'm using $_SERVRER['Document_Root'] to get the above information. I fear if I proceed with uploading this to an actual webserver the site might not work.

Is there a way where I can only get test1 so that when I create links, I don't need to worry about Document_Root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you really want to get the base url which points to `D:\xampp\htdocs\test1` or whatever subdirectory under `D:\xampp\htdocs\` you wanna call it.

Now, i assume that in `test1` directory there is an index.php file. If so, define a variable `$base_url = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`, it will return the full URL to your `index.php` file. You also might want to append a trailing slash to your `$base_url`

// Note

Maybe i misunderstood your requirements, i gave you a way to get the base url pointing to your index.php file under whatever sub-directory in `D:\xampp\htdocs\`. Now, talking about base directory, which is different, i would go around with something like:

```
$base_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
```

This variable would be defined into the `index.php` itself. Again, if you want to add a backslash/trailing slash (depending on the server environment). Append it like this:

```
$base_dir .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Comment: Thanks for th suggestion. yes test1 is the director which contains index.php and other folders. I'll just check.

Comment: My webfolder test1 cotains the file index.php and two folders 'Images' and 'Pages' when i call an image from index.php then i'm using images/1.png but when i have to call the same image from a page in the folder 'Pages' then i need to use /images/1.png my challenge is can i elimiate this '/'. because when i call /images/1.png from index.php, it does nto work

Comment: When you use relative URLs beginning with `/` , let's say `/images/1.png`, webbrowsers will interpret the resource as being located at `http://domain.com/images/1.png` and not at `http://domain.com/test1/images/1.png`, unless DOCUMENT_ROOT really points to `D:\xampp\htdocs\test1` diretory.

Comment: It now gives me this in page source but does not display the image D:\xampp\htdocs\test1\images\r2.png

Comment: Take a look to your browser's debug console. Maybe the image doesn't really exist in that directory or it has wrong file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVRER['Document_Root'] defines The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.So as you can see you can have this on any server which supports apache. You can give it a try by uploading your website on a free hosting site( such as 000webhost.com). I hope my answer was suffecient.thank you

Answer (score 0):

always make one absolute path that help you to prevent these kind of issues and make one if else statement

like when you are on your localhost use this and when you upload your files on online web server then use this

example

```
$hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if($hostname == 'localhost' )
{
  $csabosultepath = '/final';
  $absolutepath="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$csabosultepath.'/';
}
else {
  $absolutepath="https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have two queries: 1) Won't this add a lot of processing time to my pages 2) I Understand locatlhost, what are you refering to by dell or engr02 over here

Comment: my pleasure :)
1 - nop
2 - actually these my local machine names ;) i removed that from code now check